# Prove or disprove : $P[A|B] = P[B]$, the A and B are independent? Is this right?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, probability-inequalities, conditional-independence

SOrry if this is extremely easy.
I did the following but I'm a little bit unsure about it:

> Let $A=B$, and $P[A]>0$.
> Then $$P[A|A] = P[A]$$
> But A is not independent with itself:
> $$P[AA] = P[A] \neq P[A]^{2} = P[A]P[A] $$
> Thus, the preposition does not hold.

I'd appreciate your comments on this one.
Thanks!

Comment: Just insert the definition of the conditional probability in $P(A|B)$.

Comment: Is this a textbook or study question? This independence relationship is not really something to proof but more like a definition. How do you define independence?

Comment: Based on the answer by markowitz I see now that there is another interpretation. The sentence is not very clear. $$\text{P[A|B]=P[B], the A and B are independent}$$ What does it mean? Should I read this as $$\text{If P[A|B]=P[B], then the A and B are independent}$$  or is it $$\text{P[A|B]=P[B] if the A and B are independent}$$

Answer (score 6):

The error in the quoted reasoning is in  $P[A|A] = P[A]$. Instead we should have: $$P[A|A] = 1 \neq P[A]$$

For example, let the event be '$A = \text{it rains}$'.

Say you live in the desert where it almost never rains, but suppose that it is raining outside, then what is the probability that it is raining outside?

---

Edit: I notice now that you have to prove or disprove $P[A|B] = P[B]$. I misread this as $P[B|A] = P[B]$ which is true by definition when $A$ and $B$ are independent.

> $P[A|B]=P[B]$ if the $A$ and $B$ are independent

This is not true. Counterexamples occur when $P[A] \neq P[B]$.

In case of independence you have by definition $P[A|B] = P[A]$ and that means that for any case where $P[A] \neq P[B]$ you have $$\rlap{\overbrace{\phantom{P[A|B] = P[A]}}^{\text{by definition}}} P[A|B] = \underbrace{P[A]\neq P[B]}_{\text{by assumption}}$$ Thus $P[A|B] = P[B]$ does not (necessarily) follow from independence, it is only true when also $P[A] = P[B]$ and the statement fails in cases where $P[A] \neq P[B]$.

> If $P[A|B]=P[B]$, then the $A$ and $B$ are independent

This is neither true.

Counterexample: Any case where dependent $A$ and $B$ are dependent but $P[A|B]=P[B]$. (alternatively one can use cases with $P[A] \neq P[B]$)

An example is the case where we toss a fair coin two times and define $B$ be the event 'heads on the first toss', and let $A$ be the event 'heads on both tosses'. Then the table of probabilities looks as following

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
& \text{A: heads both tosses} & \text{not A: no heads both tosses} \\
\text{B: heads first toss} & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
\text{not B: no heads first toss} & 0 & 0.5 \\
\end{array}
$$

From these we can deduce $$P[A|B] = \frac{P[\text{$A$ and $B$}]}{P[\text{$A$ and $B$}]+P[\text{(not $A$) and $B$}]} = \frac{0.25}{0.25+0.25} = 0.5$$

and

$$P[B] = P[\text{$A$ and $B$}]+P[\text{(not $A$) and $B$}] = 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.5$$

And in this case we have $P[A|B]=P[B]$ but $A$ and $B$ are dependent. Therefore the statement is proven false by contradiction.

The condition $P[A|B]=P[B]$ does not (generally) imply that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: You conclude "Thus $P[A|B]=P[B]$ does not necessarily follow from independence". This seems a bit misleading conclusion. We can said that this condition in general prove dependence.

Comment: @markowitz Could you explain a bit better why it is a misleading conclusion. You state *"We can said that this condition in general prove dependence.?"* But that is not at all true. The condition $P[A|B]=P[B]$ does *not* in general prove dependence.

Comment: I try to explain. As you already read, in my answer I pose some condition at the start of the reasoning. Conclusion come from that. I exclude only special cases, so my reply remain quite general. This two point justify my conclusion, I confirm it. Your reasoning seems me quite sophistic because you, as opposite to me, exploit a lot the special case $P[A]=P[B]$. You reiterate your conclusion "The condition $P[A|B]=P[B]$ does not (generally) imply that A and B are independent".

Comment: Litterally this in not wrong but, following your reasoning, I can conclude that "The condition $P[A|B]=P[B]$ imply that A and B are independent only under the condition $P[A]=P[B]$ ". This sound different and, in my opinion, better. However this strategy sems me contorted as teaching strategy.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid special cases let me consider that $P[A] \neq P[B]$ and both $<1$

I suggest you to think about conditioning as information gained.
So even intuitively $P[A|A]=P[A]$ is a nonsense. Indeed this is like to say "If I know that $A$ happen the probability that it happen remain unchanged". While it is obvious that $P[A|A]=1$

Now

> Prove or disprove : $P[A|B]=P[B]$, the A and B are independent? Is
> this right?

if we known that $P[A|B]=P[B]$ we can conclude that $A$ and $B$ are dependent events.
Indeed this is like to say "If we known that $B$ happen, then $P[A]$ change and become equal to $P[B]$.

Comment: The situation $P[A|B] = P[B]$ can also happen when $A,B$ are independent. E.g. consider coin flips where $A$ is the event of heads on the first flip and $B$ is the event of heads on the second flip. When we consider that the results from the flipping are iid Bernoulli distributions with parameter $p$ for the probability of heads then we have $P[A|B] = P[B] = p$ but this does not imply that $A$ and $B$ are dependent. We do have some *sort* of dependence, *"the probability of A depends on the probability of B"*. But that is different from  *"the probability of A depends on the outcome of B"*.

Comment: *"then P[A] change and become equal to P[B]."* From $P[A|B] = P[B]$ we can not deduce that $P[A]$ changes if the event $B$ occurred.

Comment: It seems me that your example work if $P[A]=P[B]=p$. But my initial statement was inserted in order to avoid cases like this.

Comment: What allows you to make that initial statement? That statement can not be made without loss of generality. The statement makes that your proof only works when $P[A] \neq P[B]$. So it doesn't proof that you can conclude from $P[A|B] = P[B]$ that $A$ and $B$ are dependent.

Comment: "What allows you to make that initial statement?" I reply above. It is my wish to avoid special cases. It not for myself but for help beginners, like the asker seems to be.

Comment: I believe that this would only confuse readers. You are ending up with a statement *"If we known that P[A|B]=P[B] we can conclude that A and B are dependent events"*, which is not generally true. It is not to be considered a proof of that statement by excluding the special cases in which the statement would be false.

Comment: Indeed I think that the question is not clear enough. This is not a surprise for me. Indeed doubts of beginners frequently come from imprecise questions more than wrong answers. I interpreted it more natural and easy possible. So my answer.

Comment: I suspect that your answer /interpretation do not help beginners, like asker. For this reason i write that your conclusion in misleading and add mine. I never said that you are wrong. If you want defend your position you can, but it sems me a sofistication. I stop here.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this first let's talk about the independent and not independent events:

Independent events is when we roll a die and then flip a coin. The number showing on the die has no effect on the coin that was tossed. Therefore these two events are independent.

Not independent would be the gender of each baby in a set of twins. If the twins are identical, then both of them will be male, or both of them would be female.

Since A and B are independent so:

[image: a and b]= P(A) x P(B)

so

P[A | B] = [image: a and b] / P(B) = (P(A) x P(B)) / P(B) = P(A)

[image: ARROW]

In other hand A is not independent with B:

[image: A and B] = P(A) x P(B|A)

P[A|B] = [image: A and B] / P(B) = P(A) x P(B|A) / P(B)

[image: ARROW]

**So A and B must be independent.**

In case A and B independent and A = B:

[image: PAA]

[image: ASQUEARE]

[image: ANSWER]

Comment: *"the die has no effect on the coin"* Not having an effect relates to causal relationships. Statistical independence is different. Two events can be statistically independent even when there are variables that have an effect on each other (for example due to presence of other variables that have an 'effect'). And the other way around can happen as well, a die may not have an effect on the coin, but they can be statistically dependent due to presence of other effects.

Comment: absolutely but in this question didn't said any thing about statistical independence.

Comment: the probability that a fair coin shows "heads" after being flipped is 1/2, slash, 2. What if we knew the day was Tuesday? Does this change the probability of getting "heads?" Of course not. The probability of getting "heads," given that it's a Tuesday, is still 1/2, slash, 2. So the result of a coin flip and the day being Tuesday are independent events; knowing it was a Tuesday didn't change the probability of getting "heads."

Comment: Not every situation is this obvious. What about gender and handedness (left handed vs. right handed)? It may seem like a person's gender and whether or not they are left-handed are totally independent events. When we look at probabilities though, we see that about %10, percent of all people are left-handed, but about %12, percent of males are left-handed. So these events are not independent, since knowing a random person is a male increases the probability that they are left-handed.

Comment: for independence with probabilities please check this link :
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/probability-ap/stats-conditional-probability/a/check-independence-conditional-probability

Comment: The question is about equations with probabilities and that implies that it is about statistical dependence. For causal relationships the probabilities do not matter. You can have $P(A) = P(A|B)$ while there is a causal relationship between $A$ and $B$ and you can have $P(A) \neq P(A|B)$ while there is no causal relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I do not get the point about the example with the independence between Tuesday and coin flipping. Is it a response to my comments?

Comment: @LeventÖzdemir, the reasoning that bring you to said that $P[A|A]=P[A]$ is inconsistent.

Comment: Ok, you add $P[A|A]=1$ just now.

Comment: Our site supports $\TeX$ enclosed in `$` (inline) or `$$`.

Comment: @markowitz P[A|A] is proved in the lines in case independent,

Comment: @markowitz 5 hours a go i edited it 

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much i am new here and searched in google how to write equations and i found the way i used, can you give me a link to learn more about the way you said.

Comment: @LeventÖzdemir see e.g. https://www.docx2latex.com/tutorials/Mathematical-equations-LaTeX.html/

Comment: @Tim Thank you again  